# Webbrowser control document seem to be incomplete

Tags: c#, vb.net

I use the webbrowser control in my program but when , after navigate to a site , i try to get some element on the using the document of the webbrowser  (like getelementbyid ... ) i notice that some element are missing.

i know that elements are dynamically inserted into the page by some javascript.

i searched method to get those element and i try to get them injecting a javascript   to be executed in the page and return some element by window.external method (or just to try by alert) but even if this script are executed they just return the same result as the method on the document in the original code.

there's a way to access to this 'invisible' element in my program in some way just like i access them by pressing F12 in Internet Explorer ?
thank for your answer and sorry for my bed English.

Here is my code:

```
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //injecting and executing my javascript code
        HtmlElement head = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
        HtmlElement scriptEl = webBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("script");
        IHTMLScriptElement element = (IHTMLScriptElement)scriptEl.DomElement;
        element.text = "function sayHello() {  window.external.f1(document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML); }";
        head.AppendChild(scriptEl);
        webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("sayHello");


        String  v;
        System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\\test.txt");
        foreach (HtmlElement k in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("html"))
        {
          v=  k.OuterHtml;
          file.WriteLine(v);
        }

        file.Close();

    }
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class MyScript {
    //function called by the javascript    
    public void f1(string s)
    {
        System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\\test2.txt");
        file.WriteLine(s);
        file.Close();
    }
    }
```

at the end of the execution both test and test2 have the same html were some element are missing.

Answer (score 0):

You should be more specific in you question, and past here the code where you get the problem. Perhaps you aren't accessing the right part of the document